# VSCode on M1 Mac wont run "dotnet ef" command in Terminal

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am not sure if EFCore is supposed to work for M1 Mac being in 6.0.0 preview version. I was doing a udemy course and came to a stop where I was not able to run "dotnet ef" command in Terminal to do migrations.

```
me@my-MBP-2 dotnet-rpg % dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef 
Tool 'dotnet-ef' was reinstalled with the latest stable version (version '5.0.8').

me@my-MBP-2 dotnet-rpg % dotnet ef -h    
me@my-MBP-2 dotnet-rpg %
```

I tried to update all the EFCore packages to 6.0.0 version thinking that my resolve but still no go.

Here's my .csproj file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>dotnet_rpg</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="8.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="5.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="5.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0-preview.6.21352.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.0-preview.6.21352.1">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.0-preview.6.21352.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.0-preview.6.21352.1">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Can you suggest if I am doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

You can try uninstalling the previous dotnet-ef and install again.

```
dotnet tool uninstall dotnet-ef --global
dotnet tool install dotnet-ef --global -a arm64
```

this is only valid for M1 chip MacBooks.This will make it running dotnet ef commands.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the issue: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/25927

You can install `dotnet-ef` locally as a solution:

```
dotnet new tool-manifest # if you are setting up this repo

dotnet tool install --local dotnet-ef --version 6.0.0-rc.2.21480.5
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I've ran into the same issue and it appears that `dotnet ef` is not working on M1 processors yet.</strike>

For my project I had to generate migrations scripts by checking out my working branch on Windows machine and run the same command (with same dotnet versions) successfully.

On Parallels with Windows 11 I can not get `dotnet tool` to work (exceptions thrown) and can not test it out properly.

Updated:

I've found a solution on github which solved the issue on M1 Mac.
The `dotnet ef` tool has to be signed manually with command:

`codesign -s - ~/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef`

More details can be found here:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/25927#issuecomment-942198498

Comment: I encountered same problem here. :-/ Previous solution from ZhengGuo doesn't work for me unfor